# Launch program with a scheduler

Tags: java, task, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have a Java program running on Windows.

It has reminders/timers and I'm currently using Quartz to execute jobs every days. However, when my app is closed, the jobs are not executed.

So, I'm wondering how to start-my-application and/or run-my-jobs when the reminder needs to be fired.

Maybe with the Windows Scheduler? Or start my program at system's startup?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a task with the windows scheduler to run evry day on start up or simply add it to the auto start folder.

run mmc and add the scheduler snap-in. You shuold  find evrything you need in the Trigger(which user,time etc) and Action (which app)  Tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need something that is automatic for the user (only via my application).

Comment: You can run a Script from your app to create a task or delete it.maby this link is helpful for you http://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Okay, what is the equivalent if the user is on Linux or Mac ?

Comment: i m not so expirienced with linux but the cron daemon should be able to handle this

Comment: Hmm... Sorry but I prefer an plateform independant solution.